# Mongoose - access model from doc

Tags: methods, model, mongoose

I encountered the situation that I needed the model before defining it. In `someMethod()`, I tried `this.model('Goods')` to retrieve the model. I wondered that if there's a better way.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , GoodsSchema = require('./schemas').GoodsSchema
    , GoodsModel;


GoodsSchema.methods.someMethod = function () {
    // need GoodsModel here
    // GoodsModel.find()....    
};

GoodsModel = mongoose.model('Goods', GoodsSchema);
module.exports = GoodsModel;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.model("Goods").find()
```

See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods).

Comment: Are there differences between the two approaches?

Comment: Using my approach you don't need to define a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) simply do

```
var model = mongoose.model( 'Goods' );
```